A simpler proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number?
Assuming that $\sqrt{2}=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$.
That implies that $p^2=2q^2$, and since $p$ is a natural number then the right hand side $2q^2$ must be a square of natural number and hence $2=n^2$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Since no natural number satisfies the equation $2=n^2$, then $\sqrt{2}$ can't be rational number.
Is this a valid proof?

No, I don't think there is an easier proof. This standard proof is the easiest.

"And hence $2 = n^2$ where $n \in \mathbb N$" - why?

I have always thought about it as the left hand side having an even number of factors of $2$ (because of the square), and the right side having an odd number of factors of $2$. Probably my favourite proof because it generalises very easily to roots of any non-square number

@DietrichBurde no it doesn't actually answers my question.

@mihaild because $p^2$ is natural number, then it could be written as a product of squares of natural numbers

You need to reference something for why $2=n^2.$ Presumably, you are using unique factorization, but if you wrote that step out, it would not be a "simpler proof."

@ThomasAndrews So it's a valid proof even if not "simpler" ?

as @mihaild said, your $2=n^2$ where $n \in \mathbb{N} $ part needs work. You cannot leave things out of a proof to make it "simpler". For example, if you're using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic you have to explicitly write that.

"Because $p^2$ is natural number, then it could be written as a product of squares of natural numbers." Sure it can, for example $p^2 = 1^2\cdot p^2$ is one way to do it. But how you know that you can write $p^2 = n^2q^2$ for some $n$?

This new proof is incomplete.

This is the step that I think is invalid (without further justification at least):
You know that $2q^2$ is the square of an integer, and clearly $q^2$ is the square of an integer. In your next line, you claim this implies that $2$ is the square of an integer. But as far as I can tell, all we can really say from this information is that $2$ is the square of a rational number. (Indeed, this simply recovers the initial assumption $2=(\frac pq)^2$.)

I think OP is just using Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, no? Since $q^2,p^2\in\mathbb{Z}$?

When writing a proof, we need to communicate what we're using.

I see. I suppose had he specified that the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is why he was able to reach the conclusion, then it would be valid.

Not just saying that they used the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, but also how the fundamental theorem of arithmetic implies the conclusion.

Your proof is invalid. The argument that $2=n^2,\ n\in\mathbb N$ is wrong. Even $2=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2$ can make $2q^2$ a perfect square ($p^2$). Now, you have to prove the ratio $\frac ab$ is not possible. Thus, the simplest proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt2$ is the standard one. You can learn about more proofs here.
Here, I would like to prove $\sqrt2$'s irrationality (in a different way) as follows:
By the rational root theorem, every rational root of the polynomial $n^2-2$ would have a numerator that divides $2$ and a denominator that divides $1$, i.e., the only possible rational roots: $n=\pm1,\pm2$. But $(\pm1)^2-2\neq0\neq(\pm2)^2-2$. So, its root $n=\sqrt2$ is not a rational number.
